# Angular JS Current Element select like jQuery this selector

Tags: jquery, angularjs

In jQuery have "this" selector to access this current element and its properties and related its parent, nested and native div. So in angularjs is there any option like this?

Comment: do you have any HTML for reference? DOM manipulations are for directives, which use jQLite

Comment: `this` is not a jQuery specific thing.  It is a javascript thing.  jQuery is a javascript library.  Angular is a javascript framework.  They are both built with javascript, so `this` exists in both of them.